# Webpack resolves not working (from 2.1.0-beta.25 to v2.2.0)

Tags: webpack

Updated `webpack` from `v2.1.0-beta.25` to `v2.2.0` and my resolves stopped working. Every resolve is not working. I checked the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules) and my config should  be fine:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
  modules: [
    path.resolve('./client'),
    path.resolve('./client/views'),
    path.resolve('./client/utils'),
    'node_modules'
  ]
}
```

I get the `module not found` error for every single import.

I know it might be my error, but have no idea where to look at.

This is how I was importing

```
import React from 'react'
  // should import from "node_modules"
import App from 'components/App'
  // should import from "./client/components/App.js"
import capitalize from 'string-utils'
  // should import from "./client/utilis/string-utils.js"
```

This is my directory structure

```
project-root/
  |__ webpack.config.js
  |__ client/
      |__ utilis/
          |__ string-utils.js
      |__ components/
          |__ App.js
```

EDIT: added examples for clarity.

Comment: Could you give an example how do you use `import` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was an `eslint` issue (I'm using `eslint-loader`). Updated `eslint` and now it works.